# Spring, Java - how to avoid ConcurrentModificationException when removing nested orphan entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, iterator

I can't remove list of objects without ConcurrentModificationException error. I have to remove some neted objects because I don't want to have orphans. I use solution from this: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/

My entities:

```
public class Window {

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "path_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_path_w"))
    private Path path;
}
```

Then I have:

```
public class Path {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "path", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Point> points;

    public void removePoint(Point point) {
if (point.getPath() != null && point.getPath() != this) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Point %s does not belong to path%s", point, this));
        }
        point.setPath(null);
        this.getPoints().remove(point);
    }
```

and:

```
public class Point{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "point", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PointOperation> operations;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "path_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_point_path"), nullable = false)
    private Path path;

    public void removePointOperation(PointOperation pointOperation) {
        pointOperation.setPoint(null);
        this.getOperations().remove(pointOperation);
    }
```

and:

```
public class PointOperation {

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_point_point_operation"), nullable = false)
    private Point point;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "window_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_point_window"))
    private Window window;
}
```

I want to remove all PointOperations and then all Points:

```
if (window.getPath().getPoints() != null) {
            Iterator<Point> pointIterator = window.getPath().getPoints().iterator();
            while (pointIterator.hasNext()) {
                Point point = pointIterator.next();
                if (point.getOperations() != null && !point.getOperations().isEmpty()) {
                    Iterator<PointOperation> operationIterator = point.getOperations().iterator();
                    while (operationIterator.hasNext()) {
                        PointOperation pointOperation = operationIterator.next();
                        point.removePointOperation(pointOperation);
                        operationIterator.remove();
                    }
                }
                window.getPath().removePoint(point);
                pointIterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

I get STILL ConcurrentModificationException  -how to avoid this error and at the same time remove all PointOperations and Points??? I really didn't find any solution for that!

Comment: you still call `pointpoint.removePointOperation(pointOperation)` and `window.getPath().removePoint(point)`

Comment: Yes, I wonder if when I remove this line then the question is if PointOperation will be removed from database after closing current transaction? And I think its not a solution because I have to set null value to be able to remove this object?

Comment: Hmm but according to the solution Vlad MIhalcea said about removing such a objects I need these methods (removePoint and removePointOperation)

Comment: yeah, but while itarating over the original list you can delete the element only by iterator.remove. You could make a copy of the list and iterate over that.

Comment: How can I make a copy? With a copy I get the erro from method removePoint -> added 1 minute ago

Comment: `ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<>(); temp.addAll(window.getPath().getPoints());`

Comment: and then create iterator from temp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228306/discussion-between-turo-and-matley).